# How to set the number of threads at run time (avoiding +RTS -N#)

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I wish run my parallel programs as

```
$ myprogram <args> -n 4 <args>
```

instead

```
$ myprogram <args> +RTS -N4 -RTS <args>
```

the main reason is to normalize the argument format on my programs.

I know it would can do as

```
$ myprogramwrapper <args> -n 4 <args>
$ cat myprogramwrapper
#!/bin/bash
ARG1=parse args
ARG2=...
NCORES=....
myprogram $ARG1 ... +RTS -N$NCORES
```

but it's ugly.

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use function [setNumCapabilities](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4-latest/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/GHC-Conc.html#v%3asetNumCapabilities) at runtime.